# Objective-C Setter Memory Management

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, setter

Still a little confused about Objective-C memory management. I think my confusion stems from what exactly the autorelease means.

```
NSString *theBackendResponse = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSDictionary *accountDictionary = [theBackendResponse propertyList];
[viewController setAccountDictionary:accountDictionary];
```

Now, what should I do with the accountDictionary in the setAccountDictionary method of my view controller? Right now I just set the instance variable "accountDictionary" to whatever is returned. Should I set it to a retained one, and then release the one that's returned? What should my setter code block look like, given that NSString's propertyList method is autoreleased?

By the way, if I release theBackendResponse, will I lose the accountDictionary? I assume not...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Calling `[objectInstance autorelease]` adds an object to the current `NSAutoreleasePool`. When that pool receives a `drain` message, it sends a `release` to all the objects in the pool. If any of those objects' retainCount reaches 0, they are deallocated at that point. The purpose of  autorelease is to allow you to mark an object to be released "some time in the future". This is especially useful for things like methods that return a newly allocated object but want to release it so that the caller doesn't have to take ownership of the returned object. A method might look like this:

```
- (id)myMethod {
    id myObj = [[SomeClass alloc] init];

    ...

    return [myObj autorelease];
}
```

The caller of `myMethod` would then `retain` the return value if they wanted to take ownership of the returned value or ignore it if not. When the current `NSAutoreleasePool` is drained, `myObj` will get a release message. If no other objects own it (i.e. have sent it a `retain` message), it will get deallocated.

All of this is explained in the Cocoa [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://tuvix.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html). Even if you've already read it, it's always worth an other read.

So, to answer your questions:

First, you should release `theBackendResponse`. You will leak memory if you do not. You don't need to know what `accountDictionary` does with the string: if it needs to keep a reference it will have retained `theBackendResponse`. You have an ownership of `theBackendResponse` because you `alloc`'d it, so you must relinquish that ownership (via `release` or indirectly via `autorelease`).

Second, you must retain or copy the argument to `setAccountDictionary:` if you want to keep a reference to that object or value respectively. The standard setter method looks something like this (assuming you do not need atomic semantics):

```
-(void)setAccountDictionary:(NSDictionary*)newDict {
  if(newDict != accountDictionary) {
    id tmp = accountDictionary;
    accountDictionary = [newDict copy]; //Since newDict may be mutable, we make a copy so that accountDictionary isn't mutated behind our back.
    [tmp release];
  }
}
```

You must also remember to `release` accountDictionary in the dealloc method:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [accountDictionary release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Since you appear to be using `NSViewController`, I assume you're on Leopard (OS X 10.5) in which case, you should probably be using `@property` and the `@synthesize`d getter/setter if possible. To do this, add a

```
@property (copy,readwrite) NSDictionary * accountDictionary;
```

declaration to the class `@interface`. And add a `@synthesize accountDictionary;` directive in the `@implementation` block for your controller class.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. Now I understand. I'm actually on the iPhone, using UIViewControllers, but obviously Objective-C 2.0 still applies. I'm not going to use synthesized getters/setters for this one, but I will in the future. Thanks again!

Comment: This is slightly incorrect, you should _never_ release the old object before retaining / copying the new.  If `accountDictionary` refers to `newDict` is some way, calling `release` first will prematurely release it.  I'll add an alternative solution as an answer given I can't add multiline code

Answer (score 4):

In general, one object or method should not have to care about how another is managing memory. The fact that somebody else has autoreleased something is irrelevant to you. It's simpler to think of the concept of *ownership*. So `retain` and some other methods claim ownership, and `release` and `autorelease` relinquish it. If an object needs to keep a reference to another, it should claim ownership for as long as it needs. Thus, setter methods usually either retain or copy the new value and release or autorelease the old value.

I strongly recommend reading [the Cocoa memory management guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html). They're not all that long or complicated, and it's very important to understand them.

Answer (score 3):

The set accessor method should always `copy` / `retain` the incoming value before releasing the old, in the case where the old value is the only object that owns the new value:

```
-(void)setAccountDictionary:(NSDictionary*)newDict {
    id old = accountDictionary;
    accountDictionary = [newDict copy];
    [old release];
}
```

If `accountDictionary` referred to `newDict` and the retain count for `newDict` was 1, the call to `[accountDictionary release]` before the call to `[newDict copy]` would cause the retain count to got to 0 and therefore release `newDict`.

As an example of incorrect code, where we release the old dictionary and then copy the new dictionary:

```
-(void)setAccountDictionary:(NSDictionary*)newDict {
    [accountDictionary release];
    accountDictionary = [newDict copy];
}
```

and have the following code:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [obj accountDictionary];
[obj setAccountDictionary:dict];
```

It's contrived, but it demonstrates that in the setter, `accountDictionary` and `newDict` refer to the same instance.  If the retain count is 1, the `[accountDictionary release]` line will decrease the retain count to 0, and thus release the instance from memory.  `[newDict copy]` will now refer to an invalid instance.

Comment: +1 Agreed. Could you provide an example in which this sort of situation may occur?

Answer (score 2):

Apple describes several concepts when implementing accessors: [Memory Management Accessor Methods](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAccessorMethods.html)
If you can use Objective-C 2.0, I would go with properties and dot syntax.
Properties are new in Objective-C 2.0 and provide auto accessor generation.
In the .h File:

```
@property (retain) NSDictionary* accountDictionary;
```

In the implementation:

```
@synthesize accountDictionary;
```

Synthesize generates accessor methods for your NSDictionary. (If you want to provide your own implementation, you could also do that)

Comment: I could do that, but it doesn't really help me understand what's going on in the background :)